# Navegación entre fragments

Tags: android

He estado tratando de pasar un fragmento1 a un fragmento2 por medio de un botón, lo hace pero el caso es curioso, cuando estoy en el fragmentos2 digamos que el fragmento1 esta invisible en el fragmentos2 y donde se encuentra el botón del fragmento1 lo detecta el fragmento2 y vuelve hacer la transición, me hace un ciclo

¿Podrían ayudarme? Aquí esta el código del fragmento1, el fragmento2 se denomina como Capitulo2

```
public class PrincialCentroFragment extends Fragment{
    Button capitulo1, capitulo2,capitulo3;

    public PrincialCentroFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);

        capitulo1 = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.Capitulo1);
        capitulo2 = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.Capitulo2);
        capitulo3 = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.Capitulo3);

        capitulo1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder myBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(),R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                myBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.TituloCompromiso));
                myBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.Compromisos));
                myBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                myBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.BotonAcuerdo), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Me debes tu alma >:v!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                myBuilder.show();
            }
        });

        capitulo2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.PrincipalCentroFragment,new CentroCapitulo2Fragment());
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

        capitulo3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.PrincipalCentroFragment,new CentroCapitulo3Fragment());
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Hola Jenny, trata de revisar la redacción de tu pregunta, para realizar una buena pregunta revisa [ask], saludos.